# SetStatic doesnt make my object immovable

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm spawning my SDF model with static parameter as false, model spawns, moves and is affected by physics.
What i'd like to do is to make this model static from plugin somewhere in the middle of simulation.

I tried to call model->SetStatic(true), which doesnt work. When i check model in simulation i can see that static is checked, but object is still moving and affected by other models.

[image: image description]

is_static is clearly true but model is still moving for some reason

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24068/setstatic-doesnt-make-my-object-immovable/) by [Boris94](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16899/boris94/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> I'm spawning my SDF model with static parameter as false

How are you setting the model to static at spawn time?

Setting a model to static after it's been spawned [doesn't work](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1526/entity-setstatic-does-not-work-after-the), so the model should be static from startup. As far as I know, the only way of doing this is having `<static>true</static>` inside your model's SDF.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris94](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16899/boris94/) on 2019-11-04**:
well i wanted object to spawn as static-false and after some time, i would change this from plugin at runtime to statit-true so its not affected by physics, but seems like it is not possible right now

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-11-04**:
Yes, unfortunately that's not possible yet. You could delete and respawn the model, or attach it with a fixed joint to the world and then detach it.